# VBA to change slicer selection current selected item

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

The below behaves quite strangely.
It's aim is to leave the slicer with only the item specified (in this case "Smith") with all other names not selected.
Most of the time it works but sometimes more than one item will be left selected.

What is wrong with the below and how do I achieve the required behaviour?

```
Sub myRoutine()
    unselectAllBut "Slicer_InitialAcc_Surname", "me"  
End Sub

Public Sub unselectAllBut(slicerName As String, newSelection As String)

Dim si As Object
For Each si In ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches(slicerName).SlicerItems
    si.Selected = (si.Caption = newSelection)
Next si

End Sub
```

Second attempt which doesn't work either:

```
Public Sub unselectAllBut(slicerName As String, newSelection As String)

Dim i As Integer
With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches(slicerName)
    For i = 1 To .SlicerItems.Count
        .SlicerItems(i).Selected = (.SlicerItems(i).Caption = newSelection)
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Maybe the data is causing the problem. It looks like the following:

[image]

---

**EDIT**

The following seems to work. I select all items first which seems like over-kill:

```
Public Sub unselectAllBut(slicerName As String, newSelection As String)

Dim i As Integer

With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches(slicerName)
    For i = 1 To .SlicerItems.Count
        .SlicerItems(i).Selected = True
    Next i
    For i = 1 To .SlicerItems.Count
        .SlicerItems(i).Selected = (.SlicerItems(i).Caption = newSelection)
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A bit faster way:

- first set the new selection
- second clear all others

```
Public Sub unselectAllBut(slicerName As String, newSelection As String)
```

Dim i As Integer

  With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches(slicerName)

    For i = 1 To .SlicerItems.Count
      If .SlicerItems(i).Caption = newSelection Then .SlicerItems(i).Selected = True: Exit For
    Next i
    For i = 1 To .SlicerItems.Count
      If .SlicerItems(i).Selected And .SlicerItems(i).Caption <> newSelection Then .SlicerItems(i).Selected = False
    Next i
  End With

End Sub